# How to add an async function's result to a component in Sveltekit

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

What is the syntax to add the result of an async function into a Component?

```
<script lang="ts">
import { get } from 'svelte/store'
import UsernameField from '...UsernameField.svelte'
import { readUsernameFromDatabase } from '...'
import { userStore } from '$lib/stores/userStore'
  
let uid = get(userStore)?.uid

//SOMEHOW 
await readUsernameFromDatabase(uid)
catch the result

</script>

<UsernameField username={???} />
```

The readUsernameFromDatabase function basically ready our info from a firestore DB and returns a string (username). It get's the UID from a store unit, which is read out thru this line (let uid = get(userStore)?.uid):

```
export async function readUsernameFromDatabase(uid: string) {
  const user_ref = doc(db, 'users', uid)
  const user = (await getDoc(user_ref)).data()

  return user?.username
}
```

Thank you in advance!

---

I tried to figure it out like this:

```
  async function whatever() {
    readUsernameFromDatabase(uid).then((username: string) => {
      return username
    })
  }

<UsernameField username={whatever()} />
```

But it's a fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [`{#await}` directive](https://svelte.dev/docs/logic-blocks#await) for that. It has various versions with optional blocks for showing content while the data is loading and error handling (see docs).

The simplest version without any of that would be:

```html
{#await asyncFunction() then result}
  <UsernameField username={result} />
{/await}
```

Comment: Thanks man, that was fast!
`code:
{#await readUsernameFromDatabase(uid) then result}
    <UsernameField username={result} />
{/await}
`

worked just fine